# Making map with marginal graphics like rasterVis::levelplot(margin=T)

Tags: raster, r, visualisation, ggplot2, terra

I love `rasterVis::levelplot(margin=T)` because its marginal graphics show the column (x)
and row (y) summaries of the Raster object. I think it is very helpful to visualize the raster.

Package `rasterVis` is based on `lattice`. However, I was not familar with `lattice`. It's all my fault, but I have no time to learn complex lattice package.

Is there a way to make a map like `rasterVis::levelplot(margin=T)`?

Could `ggplot2` do it?

Using the `rasterVis` package to make a complex plot is too hard for me as a non-English speaker.

```
library(terra)
library(rasterVis)
f <- system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster")
r <- rast(f)
levelplot(r)
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean "make a map"? You've made a map. Are you asking about adding other data onto the raster plot? Or adding things like a North arrow?

Comment: Hi, Spacedman. I am asking if there is a another way to add line plot along the raster-plot's longitude and latitude. Just as the graph in my question description.

Comment: What's wrong with the way you've done it? Sure there's other ways, but why should we go to the bother of that when we have a way to do it already?

Comment: Because lattice seems too hard for me(but I know it's my fault). For example, I could not add north arrow and scale bar with rasterVis::levelplot in multiple layers of  stack(brick,spatraster), although the author of rasterVis gives method in his homepage(single layer). And plot the multiple layers gives too much space between facet plot, which affacts me much.

Comment: Well, it happens that I wrote a blog post about this recently, you may want to check it https://dieghernan.github.io/202212_tidyterra-hillshade-2/

Comment: What a amazing method! You opened a new door for me, thanks a lot! @diegherman